# Java calculates the wrong average

Tags: java

Why is the average 16666.0 and not 16666.32 in java jdk 1.8? How to write it in one line that the average is rounded at 2 floating points?

```java
float[] floats = {20000.0f, 20000.0f, 10000.0f};

double average = 0;
for (Float f : floats) {
    average += f;
}
System.out.println(average);
average = Math.round(100 * (average / 3)) / 100;
System.out.println("Average salary: " + average);
```

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: `Math.round` returns a `long` in this case, so you are doing integer division. Try dividing by `100.0` instead of `100`. See the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Math.round(100 * (average / 3))` produces a `long` which is then divided by an `int`, and then casted back to a double to fit `average`

You should divide it by a `double` instead of an `int` like hereunder

```
Math.round(100 * (average / 3)) / 100.0;
```

Printing

```
50000.0
Average salary: 16666.67
```

---

Here is what I used to debug, I did it step by step

```java
average / 3 = 16666.666666666668
100 * (average / 3) = 1666666.6666666667
Math.round(100.0 * (average / 3.0)) = 1666667
Math.round(100 * (average / 3)) / 100.0 = 16666
```

Comment: It's only the last `/ 100` that's doing integer arithmetic. The rest is all already double arithmetic. Certainly nothing is doing an "implicit cast to int". Doubles do not get implicitly cast to ints.

Comment: Oh ok, I got it. You may want to clarify where the `int` expression occurs, it's not obvious.

Comment: Correct indeed, and it was rightfully downvoted, only the last part should be an integer